# Zend_Locale() replacement in ZF3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm looking for a couple of hours now for the replacement of Zend_Locale() in ZF3.

I get the feeling that it's replaced by I18n but I'm not able to figure it out.

This is where I'm refering to, I like to get a locale out of a countrycode:

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.locale.functions.html

Comment: What specific functionality are you looking for? I believe `Zend_Locale` was replaced in ZF2 by the `ext/intl` [Locale in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) and translations would be applied in ZF3 using [Zend-mvc-i18n](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n) translator Specific reference in docs: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-i18n/translation/#setting-a-locale

Comment: I solved this in a different way, not based on the Framework not i18n. You just need to you a known compare array that are widely out there.